# Odoo - get user agent string in backend?

Tags: python, odoo, user-agent, odoo-8

For some functionality in backend of Odoo, I need to use user agent information that is extracted from browser. Is there some simple way to access that through some of Odoo methods or so?

Comment: Where exactly you need this? Do you need this for website in Odoo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to get it:

```
from openerp.http import request
ua = request.httprequest.environ.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')
```

Note. `httprequest` seems to be deprecated. But for now I din't find another way to get user agent.